# The accuracy of using CNN keras is too high or too low

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm doing CNN using keras.
Sometimes there are 15,000 total datasets and sometimes 150,000.

I got 50% or 100% accuracy regardless of the number of datasets.

Everything like the number of layers and the type of activation function is the same, it's just relearned.

The np.shape of the dataset is x : (119, 112, 1), y : (2, ).

The code for my model is:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(192, 112, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=72, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=72, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=72, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=84, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=84, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=84, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=15, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.1, verbose=2)
```

Perhaps I thought that the initial weight was a problem, so I added kernel_initializer ='he_normal' to each layer, but it was still the same.

I think it's a problem with both 100% and 50% accuracy.

As a result of re-learning now, I can get 50% accuracy and show the result.

```
Epoch 1/15
 - 161s - loss: 8.0328 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 2/15
 - 120s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 3/15
 - 120s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 4/15
 - 121s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 5/15
 - 122s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 6/15
 - 121s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 7/15
 - 122s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 8/15
 - 121s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
Epoch 9/15
 - 121s - loss: 8.0327 - acc: 0.5016 - val_loss: 7.9746 - val_acc: 0.5052
```

I didn't bring all the epoch15s that haven't finished learning yet, but in general all epochs give the same results.

Using keras, I've come up with 50% accuracy too often since.
I don't think it's 100% talkative.

I don't know where the problem is.

Have you ever experienced such a case?

I want to know what the problem is.

++ pre-processing
The preprocessing process for true and false is the same except for path.

```
# -------------------------------- True Set ------------------------------- #
for index in range(len(true_folder_list)):  # 이미지 폴더 리스트 만들기
    path_normalization = os.path.join(TRUE_DIR, true_folder_list[index])
    img = cv2.imread(path_normalization, 0)

    # 0-255의 범위로 바꿔준다는 뜻
    cv2.normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    cv2.imwrite(path_normalization, img)

    if index % 5000 == 0:
        print(path_normalization)
```

++ y labels array

```
    # -------------------------------- Load True Set ----------------------------------------- #
for index in range(len(true_Data_list)):  # 이미지 폴더 리스트 만들기
    path_true = os.path.join(TRUE_DIR, true_Data_list[index])
    image_true = ImageOps.grayscale(Image.open(path_true))  # True 이미지
    image_true = np.reshape(np.asarray(image_true), (192, 112, 1)).astype(np.float32)
    data_X.append([np.array(image_true)])
    data_Y.append([1, 0])
print("Load True Set in data")
```

True has [1, 0] and False has [0, 1] because the dataset is loaded in the above way.

What I Used before keras :

```
loadDataSet()

learning_rate = 0.0005
training_epochs = 30
batch_size = 64

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 192, 112, 1])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

# Conv
W1_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 32], stddev=0.01))
L1_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1_1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 192, 112, 32)
L1_1 = tf.nn.relu(L1_1)
# Conv
W1_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 32], stddev=0.01))
L1_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(L1_1, W1_2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')  # (?, 192, 112, 32)
L1_2 = tf.nn.relu(L1_2)
# Pooling
L1_2 = tf.nn.max_pool(L1_2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') # (?, 96, 52 ,32)

.
.
.

L4_flat = tf.reshape(L4_3, [-1, 12*7*84])
Weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([12*7*84, 2]))
Bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

hypothesis = tf.matmul(L4_flat, Weight) + Bias
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#---------------------- train ----------------------#
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0
    total_batch = int(len(train_X)/batch_size)
    for i in range(total_batch):
        start = ((i + 1) * batch_size) - batch_size
        end = ((i + 1) * batch_size)
        batch_xs = train_X[start:end]
        batch_ys = train_Y[start:end]
        feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys}
        c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
    print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost =', '{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))
```

It proceeded like this.

++ When verbose = 1:
Epoch 15/15

```
64/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 2:06 - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
128/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 2:00 - loss: 8.1850 - acc: 0.4922
192/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 1:58 - loss: 7.8912 - acc: 0.5104
256/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 1:59 - loss: 7.8072 - acc: 0.5156
320/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 1:59 - loss: 7.5554 - acc: 0.5312
384/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 1:59 - loss: 7.3455 - acc: 0.5443
448/114291 [..............................] - ETA: 1:58 - loss: 7.5554 - acc: 0.5312
.
.
.
114048/114291 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0848 - acc: 0.4984
114112/114291 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0852 - acc: 0.4984
114176/114291 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0849 - acc: 0.4984
114240/114291 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0851 - acc: 0.4984
114291/114291 [==============================] - 121s 1ms/sample - loss: 8.0853 - acc: 0.4984 - val_loss: 8.1435 - val_acc: 0.4948
 - 8s - loss: 8.0065 - acc: 0.5033
```

Comment: why is the `input_shape=(192, 112, 1)` if the shape of your data is x : (119, 112, 1) 

Is the data correctly preprocessed, often times i find there the problem?  

You can also consider to a dropdown to your cnn to solve your 100% acc problem

Comment: This is because the row of input image X is 192, the column is 112, and the dimension is grayscale. 
I use cv2.normalize (img, img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) for pre-processing to normalize and then save the image.
And the image is read and used.
I've used up to two additional dropdown layers, but there was no difference.And now I'm worried that 50% will continue to appear.

Comment: Can you add pre-processing step?

Comment: now I added pre-processing below the article.

Comment: what is there inside your dataset?

Comment: I have a fingerprint in my dataset.
However, it is a fingerprint image applied in an uncommon way.
Before applying keras, I didn't get 50% accuracy, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with how to compose the image.

Comment: I don't see a problem with **model** tbh, did you check your images to confirm that they are normalized? Also can you add few lines from `y labels array`?

Comment: Since it is grayscale, it is difficult to confirm that normalize has been performed, and it was confirmed using a histogram graph. 
And I fixed the writing in connection with the y label array, but I'm not sure it's the same as what you want.

Comment: What were you using before keras? to me it sounds like a dataset issue (maybe the two classes are unevenly split between train and valid) fit's validation_split  == `Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data provided, before shuffling.` So maybe the last items are 1 class. highly unlikely, but should check

Comment: I'm using `train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split (data_X, data_Y, test_size = 0.15, shuffle = True, random_state = 625)` to distinguish between train and test, and validation is split in model.fit did. + 
What I used before keras is now added.

Comment: With TF 1.x you used the same dataset etc? That seems like a label issue.

Comment: The part that loads the dataset is the same.
If it's a label issue, can't the accuracy be 100%?

Comment: Can you change to `verbose = 1` to see the steps that you take in an epoch?

Comment: Yes, but it's too long to get a few lines.